# Truth-functional completeness

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Let the statement $?PQR$ be determined by the following truth-table.

```
P   Q   R   ?PQR
T   T   T   T
T   T   F   F
T   F   T   F
T   F   F   T
F   T   T   T
F   T   F   T
F   F   T   F
F   F   F   T
```

1. After ‘Answer:’ below, give a logically equivalent sentence of ?PQR in FOL.  But here’s the catch: you may only use the Boolean connectives (i.e. ¬, Ʌ, and V) in the sentence you give.
   I am trying to figure this assignment out; but cannot figure out the formula for determining the sentence. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

For every line whose value is $\tt T$, write a sentence describe the assignment to the variables, e.g. $P\land Q\land R$ describes the first line of the table.

Then take the disjunction of these sentences, and show that the result has exactly this truth table.

You might want to simplify that result.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am still struggling with it though; I cannot find a sentence which will produce the same truth-table in Boole as the expected one. I must be making mistakes when translating using the connectives.

Comment: Consider the sentence $P\land Q\land R$. When is it true?

Comment: When all three predicates are true the sentence is true.

Comment: Yes, so if every line in the truth table describes an assignment to the predicate this means that $P\land Q\land R$ is true if and only if we are using the assignment appearing on the first line. Given two sentences $\varphi$ and $\psi$ (whose variables are $P,Q,R$) when is $\varphi\lor\psi$ true? Exactly if we pick an assignment for which $\varphi$ is true or $\psi$ is true. So if you take the disjunction $(P\land Q\land R)\lor(P\land\lnot Q\land\lnot R)$, then it is true exactly if you chose the first line of the table, or the fourth line of the table as your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

@AsafKaragila, being a nice guy, has given you a hint, and patiently explained more in his comments. Being not such a nice guy, can I point out that your question rather suggests that you haven't been to the library and done your basic groundwork? More or less any elementary logic text will have a section, under the title "expressive completeness" or some such, which will explain this idea. Faced with such a very basic question like this, your first reaction should be to check out two or three texts about the relevant principles at stake, till you find one whose explanations give you that "Aha! Got it!!" feeling.

Comment: [Comes to mind...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5mxXEIcQCc)